# ssh on python script returning none and no value

Tags: python, ssh

I am copying a python file (`abnormalattr.py`) from one linux server to another, and after that executing it on the second server with this command:

```
ssh root@machinename python tmp/abnormalattr.py
```

this returns NONE.
But if i execute from 2nd linux server like this:

```
ssh root@machinename
python tmp/abnormalattr.py
```

...it returns the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

This script was referring (rather unnecessarily obliquely) to `os.environ["HOSTNAME"]`.

Instances of bash invoked as interactive login shells -- as created by `ssh hostname` to an account configured to use bash with no further arguments -- source `/etc/profile` (if present), followed by the first to exist of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile`. (Interactive non-login shells run `~/.bashrc`).

When you run `ssh hostname 'some-command'`, the command is run in a *noninteractive* shell. It thus does not have the benefit of `/etc/profile` or any of these other scripts.

---

To get the hostname in a manner which does not rely on shell initialization, use the `socket` library in Python:

```
import socket
print(socket.getfqdn())
```

Comment: any suggestions for:-
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated